# MvcSiteMapProvider shows all menuitems even when the user isn't authorized for the action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, unity-container, simplemembership, mvcsitemapprovider

I'm trying to configure `MvcSiteMapProvider` into my project and the `MvcSiteMapProvider_SecurityTrimmingEnabled` parameter doesn't seem to work. The keylines of my project are :

- Visual Studio 2013
- ASP.Net MVC4
- Unity IoC container
- SimpleMembership Provider
- MvcSiteMapProvider was installed through NuGet
- `MvcSiteMapProvider_SecurityTrimmingEnabled`  set to `true`

When I run the project, every menu is shown, even if the user is not authenticated or is not authorized for the action.

How can I get it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Configuring-MvcSiteMapProvider#wiki-code-as-configuration), all configuration must be provided by the DI configuration when using an external DI container. This is primarily due to the fact that when using external DI, the multiplicity of many of the settings could change depending on how it is configured.

So, in other words, `MvcSiteMapProvider_SecurityTrimmingEnabled` in web.config/appSettings will have no effect when using external DI.

To supply this setting, you need to use the `/DI/Unity/ContainerExtensions/MvcSiteMapProviderContainerExtension.cs` file (the module). Near the top of the file, there is a variable called securityTrimmingEnabled that needs to be set to true to enable security trimming.

```
bool securityTrimmingEnabled = true;
```

You can change this file as needed to inject your own implementation of any of the interfaces or to disable many of the built-in features that don't make sense for your application.